# Javascript SyntaxError: Unexpected Token '('

Tags: javascript, class, setter, getter

I'm having a strange issue when defining a method named `get` or `set` inside a class. For example, I am defining the class Mem as follows:

```
class Mem {
    constructor() {
        this.list=[]
    }

    get(index) {
        return this.list[index];
    }

    set(index, value) {
        this.list[index] = value;
    }
}
```

But I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('`

However, when I change the method name to `geta` or `seta`, the class definition works and I don't get the SyntaxError.

```
class Mem {
    constructor() {
        this.list=[]
    }

    geta(index) {
        return this.list[index];
    }

    seta(index, value) {
        this.list[index] = value;
    }
}
```

I checked that `get` and `set` were not restricted keywords in Javascript, so I am confused as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like an error with whatever environment you're running it through. Copying and pasting your code in Chrome works fine.

Comment: Just checked and it works on Chrome. It seems that this error only comes up on Safari.

Comment: You're rushing using ES6 technologies (`class`) on browsers that still don't  *fully* support it. Please refer always to the compatibility table.

Comment: Does it work if you use `["get"]` instead of `get`?

Answer (score 0):

You are colliding with the [getter and setter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
{get prop() { ... } }
{get [expression]() { ... } }
```

Comment: Not true. That's a different syntax entirely. Try running this in your console (I'm running Chrome). `var obj = { get() { return 'hey'; } }; obj.get()` It's perfectly valid to declare a function named `get` or `set`.

Comment: @MikeC I must agree that it's a specific browser ES6 compatibility flaw.

Comment: Nina is right on this! It's ES6 and typescript syntax.